# Bubble Sort algorithm in Lua will not work

Tags: lua, bubble-sort

I am currently learning Lua, and I am attempting to create a bubble sort algorithm with it. However, I am unable to get this to work. Is anyone able to point out why?

Some details I can point out are that, on shorter lists such as lists 3 elements long, the algorithm does succeed in sorting it but then continues to sort it as if it was not sorted. On longer lists such as lists 5 elements long, the program does not sort it at all. I have gotten this information by making the program print the list every time two elements are swapped.

```
user_input = 0
list = {}

while user_input ~= "SORT" do
  print("Input number value, or input SORT to start sort")
  user_input = io.read()
  if user_input ~= "SORT" then
    table.insert(list, user_input)
  end
end

done = false
while done == false do
  done = true
  for k, v in pairs(list) do
    if k ~= 1 then
      if list[k] < list[k - 1] then
        list[k], list[k - 1] = list[k - 1], list[k]
        done = false
        for k, v in pairs(list) do
          io.write(v .. " ")
        end
        print()
      end
    end
    if k == 1 then
      if list[k] < list[table.maxn(list)] then
        list[k], list[table.maxn(list)] = list[table.maxn(list)], list[k]
        done = false
        for k, v in pairs(list) do
          io.write(v .. " ")
        end
        print()
      end
    end
  end
end

io.write("RESULT: ")
for k, v in pairs(list) do
  io.write(v .. " ")
end
print()
```

Comment: What version of lua are you using? `table.maxn` is not in version 5.3

Comment: I am using 5.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

In Lua there are 2 functions for creating iterators for tables [pairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pairs) and [ipairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-ipairs)

With `pairs` the order produced is indeterminate, it will returned all key, value pairs but the order can not be garenteed.

- You can find this under [next](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next) in the reference manual for Lua 5.1
- example: `{1,2,3,4,5}` the output could be `5,2,4,1,3`

the order of `ipairs` is `1` to the first `nil` it will not return any non-integer keys.

- example: {1,2,3,nil,5} would give you 1,2,3

Using `pairs` your algorithm's output could be correct but could appear incorrect due to the ordering from `pairs`

You want you use `ipairs` to evaluate your algorithm's output, so that it will be ordered by index.

---

Your algorithm does not perform a bubble sort as it is now, I can include corrections for that if you want. For this initial answer I think clearing up what would create an inconsistent output should point you in the right direction.

A bubble sort should "sort" 1 index at a time, the first pass will get the last value of the array sorted. then each pass after sorts following position. for example:

- before first pass `2,1,3,4,5,8,7,6`
- after first pass `1,2,3,4,5,7,6,8`

Wikipedia has great pages for sorting algorithms with gif images that can really help understand how it should function: [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Answer (score 0):

You're using pairs() instead of ipairs()
plus your code has an extra maxn() routine that isn't needed.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

local user_input = 0
local list = {}

while user_input ~= 'sort' do
    print( 'Input number value, or input SORT to start sort' )
    user_input = io.read() :lower()
    --  the word 'sort' doesn't return a number, thus no final insertion
    table.insert( list, tonumber( user_input ) )
end

local found_swap = true
while found_swap do
    found_swap = false
    for i = 2, #list do
        if list[i] < list[i -1] then
            list[i], list[i -1] = list[i -1], list[i]
            found_swap = true
        end
    end
end

io.write( 'RESULT: ' )
for i, v in ipairs( list ) do
    io.write( v ..' ' )
end
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my implementation, a couple notes:

My version of lua (luau) supports type checking etc. so you may need to remove `: table` from the paramater. (If you'd like to find more out about luau - here's the link: https://roblox.github.io/luau/ - it's really cool)

```
local function bubbleSort(t: table)
    local function check(i, v)
        local nextNum = t[i+1]
        if nextNum and (nextNum < v) then
            t[i] = nextNum
            t[i + 1] = v

            return true
        end
    end

    local changeMade
    repeat
        changeMade = false
        for i, v in next, t do
            changeMade = check(i, v) or changeMade
        end
    until changeMade == false
end

local tableForSorting = {2,5,4} --2,4,5
bubbleSort(tableForSorting)
print(tableForSorting)
```

Hope this is of some help and shows how you can really slim down your codebase and it still work exactly the same! The reason yours wasn't working - as others - have mentioned is pairs() doesn't consistently order the list the same way.

In practise we use `pairs()` for *dictionaries* while we use `ipairs()` for arrays. You'll notice i'm using `next` in this example, next is exactly the same as `ipairs()`. Drop a question below if you have any follow up questions :)!